# Connectin time out for SSL port 22 when git push on bitbucket

Tags: git, ssl, timeout, bitbucket

When I push to a remote repo on `bitbucket`, it gives me the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I found a solution that's been mentioned to disable SSL verification on your commit. So I used it for my push:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false push origin master
```

But again it gives me the same error. I'm almost sure that it is related to `https` protocol. It was fine a couple days ago, but now nothing can be pushed by me or other team members from different cities.

What is the solution to disable SSH entirely and use `https` for push. Any help?

Comment: The `http.sslverify` setting has nothing to do with `ssh`. `http` and `ssh` are two different protocols.  It looks as if there may be something blocking you from connecting to the `ssh` port on `bitbucket.org`.  You could try changing the remote url to use `https` instead.

Comment: Port 22 is traditionally used for SSH, not for anything that uses SSL/TLS (not HTTPS). It looks like you have configured your repository to use SSH, not HTTPS anyway (hence `http.sslVerify=false` would have no effect). What you get is a timeout (you might have a firewall or something, but that's not an SSL verification issue).